# XML To Pandas Dataframe - Reshape Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

In advance, I appreciate all the help that is offered to me.  I did look for an answer to my problem through the forum and found some inspiration which really helped me get started, but am still having issue trying to accomplish what I need.  Essentially, I have a generated XML file that I want to pick out certain items and move into a pandas data frame to conduct further analysis on.  The XML file is basically the XML of an Excel report generated by Crystal Reports.  Below is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
<ReportHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
</Section>
</ReportHeader>
<Group Level="1">
<Group Level="2">
<Group Level="3">
<GroupHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Text Name="Text26"><TextValue>10/9/2019 - 11/7/2019</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text25"><TextValue>Report Period:</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<Text Name="Text23"><TextValue>Form:</TextValue>
</Text>
<Field Name="GroupNameiFormID1" FieldName="GroupName ({spReporter_AgentsTrendByquestionOrsection;1.iFormID})"><FormattedValue>9-SQC_SOCC_v3</FormattedValue><Value>9-SQC_SOCC_v3</Value></Field>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="2">
<Text Name="Text1"><TextValue>Click on Form Name for Drill Down...</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="3">
<Text Name="Text18"><TextValue>Groups</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text17"><TextValue>Group:</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="4">
<Picture Name="Picture3" GraphicType="OLE">
</Picture>
<Text Name="Text16"><TextValue>Taf, Est</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text9"><TextValue>Agent:</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
</GroupHeader>
<Group Level="4">
<GroupHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Text Name="Text14"><TextValue>The second number is the number of times the question was answered.</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text15"><TextValue>The first number is the average score.</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text12"><TextValue>In each cell:</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
<Section SectionNumber="1">
<CrossTab Name="CrossTab4">
<RowGroups>
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">1.a. Did the agent thank the applicant for calling?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="1">1.e. Did the agent mention the company name?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="2">1.f. Did the agent identify themselves and their location to the applicant?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="3">1.g. Did the agent offer assistance to the caller?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="4">2.a. Did the agent identify the applicant information using Invitation Code, DOB, Social, or Name &amp; Mailing Address?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="5">3.a. Did the agent ask for the applicant&apos;s email address?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="6">3.b. Did the agent request the purpose of the loan from the applicant?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="7">3.c. Did the agent identify the desired loan and payment amount from the applicant?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="8">3.d. Was the information stated by the applicant entered accurately into the system?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="9">3.e. Did the agent recite the Debt Consolidation Disclosure?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="10">4.a. Did the agent identify the employment status of the applicant?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="11">4.b. Did the agent gather the employer name of the applicant, if employed?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="12">4.c. Did the agent gather the applicant&apos;s gross income information?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="13">4.d. Did the agent identify the applicant housing status (own/rent) and if renting did agent obtain housing expenses?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="14">4.e. Did the agent recite the Credit Authorization Disclosure?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="15">4.f. Was the employment &amp; income information stated by the applicant entered accurately into the system?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="16">4.g. Did the agent recite the Income Disclosure?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="17">4.h. Did the agent recite the Additional Income Disclosure?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="18">6.a. Did the agent offer the applicant the loan that best suited their needs?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="19">6.b. Did the agent recite the Offer Disclosure?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="20">6.f. Did the agent recite the CA Disclosure?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="21">7.e. Did the agent ask the applicant if they wanted to enroll in Auto Pay?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="22">7.g. Did the agent recite the Credit Authorization Disclosure advising applicant that their credit score may be impacted?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="23">8.a. Did the agent ask the applicant if they have any additional questions before ending the call?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="24">8.b. Did the agent thank the applicant?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="25">9.b. Did the agent demonstrate professional demeanor throughout the call?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="26">9.c. Did the agent remain attentive and demonstrate active listening skills?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="27">9.d. Did the agent use the callerâ€™s name throughout the call?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="28">9.e. Did the agent avoid long silences during the call?</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="29">9.f. Did the agent remain confident throughout the call?</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="37">Total</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroups>
<ColumnGroups>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="0">  10/6/2019</ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="1">  10/27/2019</ColumnTotal>
</ColumnGroup>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="2">Total</ColumnTotal>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroups>
<Cells>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="5" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="6" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="7" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="8" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="9" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="10" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="11" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="11" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="11" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="12" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="12" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="12" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="13" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="13" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="13" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="14" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="14" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="14" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="15" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="15" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="15" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="16" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="16" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="16" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="17" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="17" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="17" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="18" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="18" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="18" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="19" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="19" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="19" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="20" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="20" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="20" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="21" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="21" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="21" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="22" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="22" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>0.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>0</FormattedValue><Value>0</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="22" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="23" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="23" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="23" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="24" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="24" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="24" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="25" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="25" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="25" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="26" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="26" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="26" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="27" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="27" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="27" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="28" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="28" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="28" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="29" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="29" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="29" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="30" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="30" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>2</FormattedValue><Value>2</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="30" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>3</FormattedValue><Value>3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="37" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.97</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>36</FormattedValue><Value>36</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="37" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>44</FormattedValue><Value>44</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="37" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>1.0</FormattedValue><Value>0.99</Value></CellValue>
<CellValue Index="1"><FormattedValue>80</FormattedValue><Value>80</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
</Cells>
</CrossTab>
</Section>
</GroupHeader>
</Group>
</Group>
</Group>
</Group>
<ReportFooter>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
</Section>
</ReportFooter>
</CrystalReport>
```

This represents QC/QA scorecards for call center agents which contains the form used for the evaluation,evaluation date,score for each question,number of times question was answered, and totals.  I am trying to get the XML into the following columnar format:

agent form_id evaluation_date question score number_of_times_question_answered

The issue I am having is I can get agent and form_id by looping through the elements and move to a dataframe relatively easily however when I try and loop through questions and scores, it now makes the list arrays unequal and will not put into a dataframe giving me an unequal length error, which makes sense.  I would like to just have the agent name, form_id and evaluation date repeat for each row.  Here is what I have done so far which gets me agent and form_id but do not know how to tag each set of questions and scores to the evaluation that was conducted on a specific date.  See below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

file = r'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\UCL\Agents- Trend by Question or Section.xml'
with open(file,'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

nsmap = {"r": "urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"}
tree = ET.XML(data)

df={}

for i in tree.findall("r:Group/r:Group/r:Group/r:GroupHeader/r:Section/r:Field",nsmap):
    form_value = i.find('r:Value',nsmap).text
    df.setdefault('form_id',[]).append(form_value)

for i in tree.findall("r:Group/r:Group/r:Group/r:GroupHeader/r:Section/r:Text",nsmap):
    text_attribute = i.attrib.get('Name')
    if text_attribute == 'Text16':
        agent_value = i.find('r:TextValue',nsmap).text
        df.setdefault('agent',[]).append(agent_value)
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
```

Desired results are something like this:

```
agent form_id       evaluation_date question score number_of_times_question_answered
x,y   9-SQC_SOCC_v3  10/1/2019      1a       1.0    2
x,y   9-SQC_SOCC_v3  10/1/2019      1b       1.0    2
o,y   9-SQC_SOCC_v3  10/2/2019      1a       1.0    2
o,y   9-SQC_SOCC_v3  10/2/2019      1b       1.0    2
```

Comment: From where the `agent` values `x, y`, `o, y` come from?

Comment: The x,y , o,y I just put in there as examples of agent names.  That is not what is in the xml, but the agent names is coming from here:  ```<Section SectionNumber="4">
<Picture Name="Picture3" GraphicType="OLE">
</Picture>
<Text Name="Text16"><TextValue>Taf, Est</TextValue>
</Text>
<Text Name="Text9"><TextValue>Agent:</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>```  That is in the xml from my post andis Text Name=16 text value.